# Angular: ng-src Fallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there an easy way to fallback from an `ng-src` if it's returned as `null`? Currently I'm doing this, but was wondering if there is a better way to write such a conditional:

```
<td ng-if="m.poster_path == null">
  <img src="default.jpg" />
</td>
<td ng-if="m.poster_path !== null">
  <img ng-src="{{ m.poster_path }}" />
</td>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

As angular evaluates every expression inside `{{..}}`, the following code would automatically set the img path to 'default.jpg' when `m.poster_path` is `null`:

```
<td>
  <img ng-src="{{ m.poster_path || 'default.jpg' }}" />
</td>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for what the code is doing for those not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @AvijitGupta That doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting a broken image, and this console error: `GET http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370/null 400 (Bad Request)`.

Comment: @realph You are trying to access a non-existent image, thus the error.
Check whether `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370/null` should really contain `null`?

Comment: @AvijitGupta Sorry I don't understand. I thought that was coming back as `null` and your method above would work...?

Comment: @realph It is evident from `400 (Bad Request)` that the image does not exist. Also, the condition checks for the variable `m.poster_path` value to be `null` and would still hold true for a string containing 'null'

Comment: @AvijitGupta Aha! So, is the way I previously wrote it the best way to go about doing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89532/discussion-between-avijit-gupta-and-realph).